# Script done, file is typescript in bash while creating a service

Tags: bash

I have a script file as below.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
set -e
#VBoxManage startvm "cuckoo-window" --type gui
 python ~/Downloads/cuckoo-modified-master/utils/api.py --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8090
#cd ~/Downloads/cuckoo-modified-master/web/
#  python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8008
#  python ~/Downloads/cuckoo-modified-master/cuckoo.py
```

My service script /etc/init/miscservices.conf

```
start on runlevel
script
    cd ~/Downloads/cuckoo-modified-master
     ./miscservices.sh
end script
```

I have also created a symlink in /etc/init.d/miscservices and added in startup

```
sudo update-rc.d miscservices  defaults

sudo service miscservices start
miscservices stop/waiting
```

No script started. When I start as below, them move to root mode but still no service start. But when I exit it start 2 instances of the service.Please explain this behavior.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/miscservices start
start: Unknown job: on
Script started, file is typescript
root@abc:~# sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 8090
root@abc:~# ps -aux | grep misc
root      2929  0.0  0.0  81976  2260 pts/6    S+   13:42   0:00 sudo /etc/init.d/miscservices start
root      2930  0.0  0.0   4440   652 pts/6    S+   13:42   0:00 sh /etc/init.d/miscservices start
root      2962  0.0  0.0  16192   936 pts/15   S+   13:43   0:00 grep --color=auto misc
root@abc:~#
root@abc:~#
root@abc:~# exit
exit
Script done, file is typescript
+ set -e
+ python /home/aserg/Downloads/cuckoo-modified-master/utils/api.py --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8090
Bottle v0.12.0 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:8090/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.
```

Comment: What is the best way to start a script at boot as a service. I need the following commands to run.                                                          #!/bin/bash


  VBoxManage startvm "cuckoo-window" --type gui &
  cd  /opt/cuckoo/utils/
    sudo python api.py --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8090 &
  cd /opt/cuckoo/web/
    sudo python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8008 &
    sudo python /opt/cuckoo/cuckoo.py &

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem may be in `~/Downloads/cuckoo-modified-master/miscservices.sh` script (and btw use `~` in upstart script not best idea because it will probably execute as root and there can be some problems with determitate where is `~`). By default upstart doesn't spawn processes. That mean if you have your configuration like that:

```
start on runlevel
script
    cd ~/Downloads/cuckoo-modified-master
     ./miscservices.sh
end script
```

upstart will only start your process once and then do nothing. And if you start it once and there was some error in script it just stoped with no information to you. You can check log file. By default it must be in `/etc/log/upstart/miscservices.log` (for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS). If no you can check where is default upstart logs in your OS or write it manually just by echo some informtaion in certain place. For example:

```
env logf="/home/someuser/miscservices.log"
script
    echo "Script it starting..." >> $logf
    /home/someuser/Downloads/cuckoo-modified-master/miscservices.conf >> $logf
    echo "Script is ended." >> $logf
end scipt
```

And if you want to respawn script processes you may add to the beggining of the script:

```
respawn
respawn limit unlimited
```

or just make unlimited loop in script file.

ps. You can modify your upstart script `/etc/init/miscservices.conf` by more clear code. From `start on runlevel` to:

```
start on filesystem
stop on shutdown
```

This mean that script will start after filesystem starts and will shutdown on shutdown.

pps. You dont need symlink in `/etc/init.d/miscservices`. If you use upstart then just use it! You dont need anything else. Just put your end scipt in `/etc/init` and it will start automatically. It can be something like that:

```
start on filesystem
stop on shutdown

env logf="/home/someuser/miscservices.log"
script
    echo "Script it starting..." >> $logf
    /home/someuser/Downloads/cuckoo-modified-master/miscservices.conf >> $logf
    echo "Script is ended." >> $logf
end scipt
```

Hope i can help!

Comment: you did more than help.  Thanks.